# Startup screens: "Show this page at startup" vs. "Don't show this on startup"

Tags: ios, copywriting, modal-dialog, wording, splash-screen

I'm currently working on an iOS app where the user is presented with a startup screen until the user disables it.

I am insisting that this startup screen should have an already ticked checkbox that says:
"Show this at startup".

My customer is insisting on having an un-ticked checkbox saying "Don't show this on startup".

I feel like I've seen the former more often than the latter.
What do you guys think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Checkboxes should always be shown in the affirmative**, so you shouldn't use "Don't show this on startup".

You could however use "**Hide this on startup**" as an option that doesn't have the checkbox filled, which is what I would suggest.  The action that someone will be thinking is more along the lines of "I want to hide this screen", so the action should closely follow that.

Comment: Thanks! "Hide this on startup" was the compromise I was looking for.

Comment: Haha. I just noticed that my title body of my question differ. My customer was suggesting "Don't show this on startup" as indicated by the question, but not the title.

Comment: @Nailer I fixed the title to more closely match the body of the question :)

Comment: +1: avoiding double negatives is a good thing; it's not helpful to the user to make them think about what it means to _untick_ the '_Don't show this_' checkbox.

Comment: Referring to 'hiding' a screen is a technical way of describing the situation. '_Skip this screen in future_' is a more user-friendly wording.